# sql server login credential for jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I use windows authentication, and I want to connect to mssql server with jdbc with the syntax above, what should I set in the user and password fields?

```
type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-1"
driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=AdventureWorks" 
user="sa"
password="password"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to provide username and password since you are using Integrated Windows Auth, a google search lead me to this connection string:

```
 jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

Comment: -Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x86