# Simplest Distribution Method for Java Front-end Database Application?

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

I would like to create a front-end application in Java to query a Microsoft SQL database. This application will need to be distributed to around 20 computers and must be *extremely* user friendly. I'm hoping someone can explain two things:

1. The simplest way to distribute this application across multiple windows machines. I.e.least amount of software installation and maintenance.
2. Explain how once distributed, the application might be able to connect to the database upon launch, as opposed to authenticating a user each time.

So far I plan to use Java, JavaFX, & Microsoft JDBC driver. Open to new ideas though, cheers in advance.

Comment: The most user friendly experience is to distribute nothing. Forget JavaFX and build yourself a web app using any number of frameworks. This question seems like it might attract a lot of opinions and not necessarily a lot of fact, given that the requirements consist of some broad strokes and not a huge amount of detail.

Comment: If you end up using a JavaFX app regardless, you can see the [JavaFX packaging options](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) in the tag, then choose from those for the best fit for your application.

Answer (score 1):

For distribution, I can think of a couple of choices:

1. IF you are sure that each of you 20 computers has a JVM installed, you could package the app as a "FatJar", a single Jar file with all of the dependencies in it. There are plugins for this in both Maven and Gradle.
2. If you don't have a JVM on these computers, and don't want to have to install one, you could create a native application using GraalVM and Gluon.
   Take a look at https://gluonhq.com/create-native-javafx-applications-using-graalvm-22-builds-from-gluon

If you want to connect to the database without user intervention, see [sql server login credential for jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141892/sql-server-login-credential-for-jdbc)

Comment: The easiest means of distribution of a JavaFX program probably is https://www.jdeploy.com/